# Values being truncated along the Y-axis from the plot on R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

Using `quantmod` and `chartseries`, a plot was created on R Shiny. The values to be shown along the y-axis on the plot have to be 20 000, 25 000 and so on, but what is showing is only 2 000,2 500 and 3 000 and as a result the extra 0 is being truncated on the plot along the y-axis.

How to get the correct values visible along the y-axis?

[image]

Comment: 1. Data missing
2. Code Missing

Comment: Kindly note that `dygraphs` does this task nicely too, would recommend that you use that in the future.